# Reading/Writing Cookies in farm WebParts - SharePoint 2010 Server

Tags: internet-explorer, farm-solution

I have farm solution Visual web part, with the following `write` and `read` cookies methods

```
void writeCookie(Guid thisVoteGuid, string pollID)
{
    HttpCookie pollCookies = new HttpCookie(COOKIE_NAME);
    pollCookies.Value = thisVoteGuid.ToString() + ";" + pollID;
    pollCookies.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
    Response.Cookies.Add(pollCookies);
}


string readCookie()
{
    //Get Cookie value
    HttpCookie theCookie = Request.Cookies[COOKIE_NAME];
    if (theCookie != null)
       return theCookie.Value;
     return string.Empty;
}
```

The `read` function fails to get the cookie (of-course, since the write method didnt store the cookie at all!), I checked `Temporary Internet Files` to confirm that no cookie stored

How to read/write cookies in visual webPart-Farm solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you use looks ok... Does your browser allow you to save cookies? (Since cookies are stored client-side) If you need to be sure that every user uses this, you'll need a server-side solution like viewstate, session, database,... since not every user allows cookies!

- [Cookies in Internet Explorer](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesie.html)
- [Cookies in Firefox](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesmozilla.html)
- [Cookies in Opera](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesopera.html)
- [Cookies in Netscape](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesns.html)
- [Cookies in Chrome](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookieschrome.html)
- [Cookies in Safari](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiessafari.html)
- [Cookies in other browsers](http://www.timeanddate.com/custom/cookiesother.html)

Comment: After two-three tries it worked, I don't know why, but what Im sure about that I didnt change any of the IE options!, anyway I'll accept your post as an answer, Thank you.